# Comparison of dynamic number of lists in C#

Tags: c#, linq, string-comparison

I have a variable number of List-objects, of which I need to compare the values at the same indexes. The number of entries in the list is given and does not vary.

For example:
4 Lists
each 4 entries

So what I'd be looking for in this example, is 4 bools, one per index.
Getting the indexes of unmatching entries would be fine, too.

*Pseudo:*

```
bool isFirstEqual = (list1[i] == list2[i] == list3[i] == list4[i]);
```

But I need to do this in a fashion that's applicable for a variable number of lists. I could have 6 Lists, but also 2.

I was thinking of doing something with LINQs `.Except()` but am not sure how to use it with a variable number of lists.

I am struggling to find the elegant solution that I'm sure is out there.
Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Can you come up with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Do it without linq. I don't see the problem. No doctor told you that you need linq. `for (int i...)` have been good enough for generations of programmers, they will be good enough for you.

Comment: As I don't have the logic for it, I cant. I need to compare string lists based on their indexes. if I had a complete example the question would not have been necessary. I can paste some code that makes some lists.. not sure that would help.

Comment: also, without using linq, im struggling on the logic on this as it needs to work for 2 lists as well as 6 lists. but yeah ill prob not end up using linq.

Comment: what if the lists or sequences are different lengths?

Comment: theyre not; if they are, normal exception handling will take care of it aka "Unexpected Error" + errorMsg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If i understand what you mean, something like this might work

```
public static bool IsEqual<T>(int index, params List<T>[] ary)
{
   for (var i = 1; i < ary.Length; i++)
      if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(ary[0][index], ary[i][index]))
         return false;         

   return true;
}
```

**Usage**

```
var isSecondelemEqual = IsEqual(1, list1, list2, list3,...)
```

**Update**

Basically takes a variable list of lists, and assumes you want to check the index of each list against each other.

Comment: Shouldn't `ary.Length` be `ary[index].Count`?, because then you use `ary[index][i]`, so `0 <= i < ary[index].Count`. And you should put a note that you can directly pass an array of parameters to IsEqual, to make it clearer that it can be used i a "dynamic" way.

Comment: @xanatos hrm confused abotu the length , count thing, and yeah to the last bit, let me check this, i am second guessing myself now

Comment: @xanatos i did have the indexing around the wrong way, he does want to check the index of each list against each other i think? for which the length is the param array length, or have i got this all wrong

Answer (score 1):

```
bool AreIndexesEqual(int index, List<List<int>> lists)
{
    int match = lists[0][index];

    foreach(List<int> list in lists.Skip(1))
    {
        if (list[index] != match)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given for example:

```
List<List<int>> listOfLists = new List<List<int>>
{
    new List<int> { 1, 100, 2},
    new List<int> { 2, 100, 3},
    new List<int> { 3, 100, 4},
    new List<int> { 4, 100, 5},
};
```

So a `List<>` of `List<int>`

the totally unreadable LINQ expression that will return a `List<bool>` is something like:

```
List<bool> result = Enumerable.Range(0, listOfLists.Count != 0 ? listOfLists[0].Count : 0)
            .Select(x => listOfLists.Count <= 1 ? 
                true : 
                listOfLists.Skip(1).All(y => y[x] == listOfLists[0][x])
            ).ToList();
```

Here I want to show you that if your first solution to any problem is LINQ, then perhaps now you will have two problems.

Now... What does this linq does? We have 4 `List<int>`, each one with 3 elements... So 3 rows of 4 columns. We want to calculate the result "by row", so the first thing is discover the number of rows, that is `listOfLists[0].Count` (we put a pre-check for the case that we have 0 rows). Now we generate an index (like a `for`), using `Enumerable.Range(0, numberofrows)`, like `for (int i = 0; i < numberofrows; i++)`. For each row we see if there are 0 or 1 columns (`listOfLists.Count <= 1`), then the result is `true`, otherwise we compare all the other columns `y[x]` with the first column `listOfLists[0][x]`.

With a dual `for` cycle it becomes clearer probably:

```
var result2 = new List<bool>(listOfLists.Count != 0 ? listOfLists[0].Count : 0);

// Note the use of .Capacity here. It is listOfLists.Count != 0 ? listOfLists[0].Count : 0
for (int col = 0; col < result2.Capacity; col++)
{
    if (listOfLists.Count <= 1)
    {
        result2.Add(true);
    }
    else
    {
        bool equal = true;

        for (int row = 1; row < listOfLists.Count; row++)
        {
            if (listOfLists[row][col] != listOfLists[0][col])
            {
                equal = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        result2.Add(equal);
    }
}
```

Note that both programs can be simplified: `new int[0].All(x => something) == true`, so `.All()` on empty `IEnumerable<>` is `true`. You can remove `listOfLists.Count <= 1 ? true :` and `if (...) { ... } else` up to the `else` keyword, keeping only the code inside the `else`:

```
var result2 = new List<bool>(listOfLists.Count != 0 ? listOfLists[0].Count : 0);

// Note the use of .Capacity here. It is listOfLists.Count != 0 ? listOfLists[0].Count : 0
for (int col = 0; col < result2.Capacity; col++)
{
    bool equal = true;

    for (int row = 1; row < listOfLists.Count; row++)
    {
        if (listOfLists[row][col] != listOfLists[0][col])
        {
            equal = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    result2.Add(equal);

}
```

Comment: good explanation, thanks! yeah linq is not for everything.. still cool that its possible xD

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
IEnumerable<bool> CompareAll<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source)
{
    var lists = source.ToList();
    var firstList = lists[0];
    var otherLists = lists.Skip(1).ToList();

    foreach(var t1 in firstList)
    {
        yield return otherlists.All(tn => tn.Equals(t1));
    }
}
```